# Printing a string input from scanner with leading whitespaces

Tags: java, string, io, java.util.scanner

I already have an input scanned which is of int type and then I am trying to take a second input of String type which has whitespaces at the beginning, and while printing both the inputs, I want the second one to be printed as it is (with the white spaces).

```
class Input{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();


        String s=sc.next();
        s=s+sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
4
      hello world.
```

Expected Output:

```
4
      hello world.
```

Actual Output:

```
4
hello world.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` uses the default delimiter, which will capture any whitespace sequence. Use `Scanner.nextLine()` instead:

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  // consume only the newline
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/FSvpQs)

Answer (score 1):

The default delimiter is one or more whitespace :

```
private static Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                                                "\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

So `sc.next()` produces `"hello"`
and `sc.nextLine()` that reads the rest of the current line produces `"world"`.

You could set a breakline character as delimiter for the second input and remove

`s = s + sc.nextLine();` that is not required any longer :

```
...
sc.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
String s = sc.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sc.nextLine()` instead of next().
because for `nextLine()`, token to read is entire line and for `next()`, the token to read is next word.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;
class Input{
    public static void main(String[] main){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. You should add a brief explanation in your comment